# Drush module version

Tags: drush

Is there a way for drush to print out what module version for a module that is currently enabled?

I'm not looking for trying to find what version of drush is.

I end up doing it the janky way:

`drush dl mymodule --select` and then seeing which version is installed.

Or `drush pm-list | grep mymodule`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For Drupal 7 and earlier, try using `drush pm-info module`. It may give you what you want.

For Drupal 8 and later, the `pm` commands are mostly deprecated.  To get module information, you would use `composer show drupal/module`.

Comment: This works for drupal-7. For drupal-8 look in composer.lock.

Comment: @Interlated Thanks for the reminder.  `composer show` is more readable that directly poking through the lockfile.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the shortcut:

```
drush pmi [module]
```

Answer (score 6):

This will give you a list of all the *currently enabled*, *contrib*(i.e., non-core), modules on your site along with the exact version number:

```
drush pm-list --type=module --no-core --status=enabled
```

Comment: drush pm-list | grep <modulename>